# How to use `join` method to access columns from multiple tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I have two tables, and I want to display all these columns on page.
Tables:

```
1.Users:
      name,     email, sex_id
       abc, abc@q.com,      0
2. Masters:
      type, sex,   sexn 
         8,   0, female
```

I want to display:

```
name,     email,    sex
 abc, abc@q.com, femail
```

Models' definition:

```
class Master < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :master

  def self.search(search)
    where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  end
end
```

using `@users = User.joins("INNER JOIN masters ON masters.sex = users.sex_id AND masters.type = 8")`, I can only access columns from Users.
I want to access data from Masters. Using `@users.first.master`, I just get nil.

using`@users = User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN masters ON masters.sex = users.sex_id AND masters.type = 8")`, I can access columns from these two tables. So there's no problem with my data.

How do I use `join` method to access columns from multiple tables?

Comment: You probably need to also use `includes(:masters)`  - in fact if you set up the associations correctly, you'll only need to use `User.includes(:masters).all` - otherwise you'll need to add your existing `joins` on to specify how the two tables are joined. Have you had a read of the rails guide on active record queries? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html It'll help you level up in how to use the rails interface :)

Comment: try this one `@users = User.select("users.*, masters.*").joins("INNER JOIN masters ON masters.sex = users.sex_id AND masters.type = 8")`

Comment: @Bala Karthik It works. Thanks. I'm new to Rails, and the guides of rubyonrails online are a little difficult to understand. How can I grasp fundamental skills quickly?

Comment: @niaomingjian i hope my answer solved your problem, in that case accept the answer so that it would help others who faced the same problem. And you can learn basic rails stuff from http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the select statement, try this one.

```
@users = User.select("users.*, masters.*").joins("INNER JOIN masters ON masters.sex = users.sex_id AND masters.type = 8")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! You can have Rails do the join for you with the `.includes()` method:

```
def self.search(search)
  # :master is singular
  includes(:master).where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

Then:

```
@users.each do |user|
  # singular again
  puts user.master.sexn
end
```

Comment: I debug to find that `@users.first.master` = nil, and `@users.first.sexn` undefined method 'sexn'. Using `includes` method, it still doesn't work.Using `User.select("users.*, masters.*")` Bala Karthik said, it works.